# Isolated Tag Search: Questions Having X Tag Only and Nothing Else

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

How do I search for questions tagged with Java ***and only java***?

Something like this:

[image]

### **Via Ignored Tags?**

Can I specify a wildcard tag to ignore all other tags except Java?

### **Via URL?**

Any request that I can formulate to get this isolation?

Comment: I don't think this is possible right now.

Comment: I tried `*[java]`, the accepted solution, unfortunately it doesn't work. @AlEverett

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It appears it's still unanswered?

Comment: @Ronixus why not? It has 2 answers. Bottom line, such thing is currently not possible with the existing search mechanism and I doubt it's worth adding. There is workaround by using Data Explorer or the API.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Got it. I was looking for the availability of the feature. Noted.